# How do I get OpenLayers 3 to display png tiles made in TileMill?

Tags: wms, openlayers, openlayers-2, tilemill, xyz

So I used TileMill to style the map -> mbtiles export -> mbutil used to extract files to directory. 
I'm running GeoServer and moved this files within the webapps directory that I'm using to host the map.

For reference I am using this [course page](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog585/node/711) for instruction and guidance. I am trying to build a completely FOSS system; at the end of the provided link, it instructs us to upload the extracted mbtiles to a web accessible directory and then build a layer using ESRI--I did not do that (FOSS or bust--I think I should be able to point at this if hosted on the local server). I just put the files in that aforementioned webapps folder so that I can access it from the localhost.

Now I would like to use these pngs that I've made in TileMill to display on a map in browser using OpenLayers 3. I was following the instruction on this [second course page](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog585/node/718) however they are using OpenLayers 2.

My code at the moment is as follows:

```
    var mercatorProjection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:900913');
    var map;
    function init(){

        // Add the tiled layer
        var tmsPhiladelphia = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/geog585/PhillyBasemap/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                attribution: "Data copyright OpenStreetMap contributors",
                projection: mercatorProjection
            })
        });

        // Make map
        map = new ol.Map({
            // Center the map
            view: new ol.View({
                projection: mercatorProjection,
                center: [40, -75.145],
                zoom: 12
            }),
            layers: [tmsPhiladelphia],
            // Assign to map div
            target: 'map',
            controls: ol.control.defaults({
                attributionOptions: { collapsible: false }
            })
        });

        /*
                    // Add the WMS
                    var wms = new ol.Layer.Tile({
                        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                            preload: Infinity,
                            url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/geog585/wms',
                            serverType: 'geoserver',
                            params: {
                                'LAYERS':"geog585:FarmersMarkets", 'TILED':true
                            }
                        })
                    });

                    map.addLayer(wms);

                    // Configure the query on click
                    var info = new ol.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
                        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/geog585/wms',
                        title: 'Identify features by clicking',
                        queryVisible: true,
                        infoFormat: "application/json",
                        eventListeners: {
                            getfeatureinfo: function(event) {
                                // Read and parse the query response, if there is one
                                var response = JSON.parse(event.text);
                                if(response.features.length !== 0){
                                    var returnedFeature = response.features[0];
                                    // Configure the popup
                                    map.addPopup(new ol.Popup.FramedCloud(
                                            "marketInfo",
                                            map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy),
                                            null,
                                            "<b>" + returnedFeature.properties.NAME + "</b><br />" + returnedFeature.properties.ADDRESS,
                                            null,
                                            true
                                    ));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    map.addControl(info);
                    info.activate();
         */
    }
```

When I try accessing the page, I met with a blank map. I check the console and it's given me an error that the tiles I am asking for do not exist. So the best that I can trouble shoot is that these XYZ values are not being generated correctly. I did some digging around and the best I could find was a working example using TSM but that was for OL2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are not zooming at the right place. For this reason it's possible you don't have tiles here... (not generated)

Change

```
view: new ol.View({
    projection: mercatorProjection,
    center: [40, -75.145],
    zoom: 12
}),
```

with

```
view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform(
              [-75.145, 40], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: 12
}),
```

You have a correction but for learning purpose, I will explain:

- `projection: mercatorProjection,` was removed because default projection in OpenLayers 3 is EPSG 3857 (also know previously as EPSG 900913)
- `ol.proj.transform` is to convert your EPSG coordinates from lon, lat (EPSG 4326) to EPSG 3857. Be careful, you were using lat, lon whereas OpenLayers uses lon, lat.
  See [this link](http://www.macwright.org/lonlat/) for a reminder about coordinates order; disclosure: I always forget too)

Comment: One follow up, how did you know the projection of that coord was originially 4326?

Comment: Because WGS 84 (GPS system) = EPSG 4326 = longitude, latitude in decimal degrees (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System#WGS84) = most used. Also because, you seems to be working on Philadelphia because `tmsPhiladelphia`. Searching Philadelphia at http://openstreetmap.org gives me an url like `http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=11/40.0024/-75.2385` hence my guess